# Create a text box to enter time for a specific event to happen in Tkinter and Python

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am not sure exactly how to phrase the title question any better but what I am trying to do exactly is to be able to enter a time into a widget in Tkinter to run a Python script at that time. Envision a programmable coffee maker and that is the exact function I am trying to create.

Here is the basic code (not the program itself) to simply turn something on and off. How would I code it to turn on at a set time that I could enter in the GUI?

I've tried searching Google and am not sure if I am phrasing the question right, sorry, I'm a noob.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
from gpiozero import LED
import RPi.GPIO
import time

RPi.GPIO.setmode(RPi.GPIO.BCM)

led=LED(4)

win = Tk()
win.title("LED Toggler")
myFont = tkinter.font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 12, weight = 
"bold")

def ledToggle():
    if led.is_lit:
        led.off()

    else:       
        led.on()        
        time.sleep(3)
        led.off() 

def close():
    RPi.GPIO.cleanup()
    win.destroy()

ledButton = Button(win, text='GPIO ON', font=myFont,  
command=ledToggle, fg='black', bg='green', height=1, width=10)
ledButton.grid(row=1,column=1)

exitButton = Button(win, text='Exit', font=myFont, command=close, 
bg='red', height=1, width=6)
exitButton.grid(row=2, column=1)

win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use `sleep()` in tkinter. Instead use `after()`. The reason is that sleep and wait will both cause the entire tkinter program to pause instead of just providing a timer for something.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
# you can input a string like this in the gui 
gui_time = 'Wed Aug 30 18:20:01 2017'

# this gives you the number of seconds from now until the time you specified
ETA = time.mktime(time.strptime(gui_time))-time.time()
# convert to milliseconds 
mETA = int(ETA*1000)
win.after(mETA,ledToggle)
```